# How do I get posX and posY of a translate attribute with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using `translate3d(..., ..., 0px)` for my custom drag and drop, for some reasons I need to get the position X & position Y using Javascript, just like the example below.

> transform: translate3d( **345** px,  **-76** px, 0px);

the numbers in the translate3d can vary from -9999 to 9999 when dragged.

Is there any possiblity on doing that ?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Anubhav for now I didn't try anything since I do not know which is the best way, using regex might be a problem since other attr as `scale()` may enter in the transform attribute. I asked this question to know if there was anyway to target translate3d first and second numbers only ? What would be the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the position of a div with offset() or position()

`offset()` gets your top and left position relative to the entire document

`position()` gets your top and left position to the element's parent

as you can see in the below example, position is smaller with 10px than offset because it is relative to the position of `section` which has `top:10px;left:10px`

so you can get the position/offset of the desired element in a dynamic function, like a dragable function ( i presume that's what you want to do )

so just put the `var` inside that function and it will calculate in realtime the offset/position of your element.

check snippet below

```js
var divOff = $("div").offset(),
    divPos = $("div").position()

$("div").html("offset left:" + divOff.left + "offset top:" + divOff.top + "<br>" + "position left:" + divPos.left + "position top:" + divPos.top)
```

```css
div {
 width:500px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 transform:translate(50px,100px)
}
section {
position:relative;
top:10px;
left:10px;
}
body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<div>


</div>
</section>
```